# NoClassDefFoundError when running UI Automator Viewer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to run Android's UI Automator Viewer on my Windows machine. I have the following installed:

- Latest Android Studio
- JDK 8
- Latest Android SDK

I'm running the following command:

```sh
uiautomatorviewer
```

When I run it, I get an error related to SWT:

```sh
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:650)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:632)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        ... 7 more
```

Anyone know what I'm missing?